# Running issue in IOS App

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm making an app which have left drawer, in app i make some changes in login for of customer for checking out the changes i run it on simulator, there i notice my left drawer hides, app is running perfectly but my left drawer is not showing. What should i do to go back to that situation when my drawer was visible?

[image]

Comment: you need to use third party libraries like MFSidemenu

Comment: issue is not that, it was running perfect and showing items in left drawer but when i make some change some in login form and run it all the items in drawer hide or vanish from there as in screenshot. @BrijeshShiroya

Comment: Can you put some of you code to figure out the issue?

Comment: can u give me ur email id , i can send u my project.@iUser

Comment: mailed u check it out. @iUser

Comment: Can you please add some code or share the resolution with us?